# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150528,1) into shape (150528)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to copy array to matrix (to fill row) as follows:

```
image = cv2.imread(file)    
feature = image.reshape((IMAGE_LEN, -1))
features_matrix[0] = np.copy(feature[0:])
```

but getting the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150528,1) into shape (150528)
```

the features_matrix was build with the right size (`np.zeros((NUM_OF_FILES_PER_LABEL,IMAGE_LEN))`

and `feature[0:]` (or `feature[0::]`) fit to this size.

```
print (feature.shape) gives (150528,1)
```

so what is wrong and how can I fix it ?

(I'm using python 3.7)

Comment: Do feature[0::]

Comment: same error with feature[0::]

Comment: Then you should tell us some more info about the shapes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `image.reshape((IMAGE_LEN))`